# Form text box not automatically updating

Tags: javascript

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>The Raptor Astronomer</title>
        <script>
          function getQuantity()
{
    var theForm = document.forms["formula"];
    var radiusform = theForm.elements["radius"];
    var radius =0;
    if(radiusform.value!="")
    {
        radius = parseInt(radiusform.value);
          var circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
    }
theForm.elements["circumference"].value = var circumference;
}
getQuantity();

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="formula">
            <label>Radius</label>
            <input id="radius" name="radius" type="text" />
            <label>Circumference</label>
            <input id="circumference" name="circumference" type="text"/>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

As far as I can tell from tutorials, my code should update to be the circumference - I'm not seeing that happen though.

Why is this not running correctly? Am I not including a trigger? Does there need to be a trigger?

Comment: Are you sure the function is actually being called? (alert/console.log)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `var`:-

```
theForm.elements["circumference"].value = circumference;
```

and also declare it before `if`

```
var circumference=0
if(radiusform.value!="")
    {
        radius = parseInt(radiusform.value);
        circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Made some minor changes. See the **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LvqKq/1/)**. I tied calling the script to the onchange event of the radius input element. You also can't use var as part of the assignment so I moved it to the proper position.

**JavaScript**

```
function getQuantity() {
    var theForm = document.forms["formula"];
    var radiusform = theForm.elements["radius"];
    var radius = 0;
    var circumference;
    if (radiusform.value != "") {
        radius = parseInt(radiusform.value);
        circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
    }
    theForm.elements["circumference"].value = circumference;
}
```

​**HTML**

```
 <form id="formula">
            <label>Radius</label>
            <input id="radius" name="radius" type="text" onChange="getQuantity()"/>
            <label>Circumference</label>
            <input id="circumference" name="circumference" type="text"/>
        </form>​
```